# Automaticallt start AWS/Azure VM when there is incoming traffic

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, autoscaling

I'm designing an architecture where there is a group of VMs in every cloud and region capable of handling incoming HTTP traffic. Using scale sets, I can automatically scale out and in a number of VMs in every group depending on traffic.

However, I expect that in some regions there will be no traffic at all most of the time. Having one instance running in every region of every cloud is a lot of instances, and I am looking for ways to optimize this.

Is if it is possible to automatically scale from 0 instances to 1 instance when there's an incoming request? I know it's possible to scale from 1 to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. In auto scaling group you can set the minimum number of instances to zero. Then using a CloudWatch alarm, you can scale out when there is some traffic.